# Apache Rewrite rule for url without extension

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a static site. I want to rewrite any url without extension to the url with .html extension.

For example:

If the link is "example.com/test1", let the server find "example.com/test1.html" but in the address bar keep the "example.com/test1" showing there.

I will need this rewrite rule applys to any URL without (.* or /) at the end.

I am a beginner for Apache. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn on the [MultiViews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_negotiation.html#multiviews) option and mod_negotiation will do the rest of the job. But this can lead to some [problems](http://www.gerd-riesselmann.net/archives/2005/04/beware-of-apaches-multiviews/).

Answer (score 0):

If it's only the HTML extension, then something like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+([^\ \?]+)\.html
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.html [L]
```